# Prevent images on self-hosted Wordpress from being served from Wordpress.com

Tags: multisite, images, wordpress.com-hosting

I have created a few posts with featured images on my blog. Since this is self-hosted installation, I was more than sure, that all my files were upload to my server / hosting. But to my extreme surprise, when checking source I have found, that they're served from Wordpress.com (example code: `<img src="http://i0.wp.com/BLOGDOMAIN/files/2015/08/FILENAME.png">`) instead of for example `http://BLOGDOMAN/files/2015/08/FILENAME.png`.

What am I missing? How can my private, self-hosted blog post anything to Wordpress.com? I've never agreed for something like this. I'm a privacy maniac and the only reason for spending hours on setting own, self-hosted blog network was, that I don't want to have anything related to Wordpress.com.

Can someone enlighten me, what is causing this strange (at least to me) behavior of my self-hosted blog? Is this some magic in theme that I use or a hidden feature of Jetpack? Is there any way to disable this? Can I have my private, self-hosted blog network really private and prevent it from sending or uploading anything to Wordpress.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photon is the part of jetpack that uploads your images to wordpress.com so they can be served from their CDN. You can turn it off here: yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules&module_tag=Photos%20and%20Videos